# Accidentally cut bridge on neutral side of outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Originally I was installing a switch controlled outlet, but broke the neutral side rather than the hot side bridge. Can this outlet still be used on another regular outlet if I pig tail the neutral wire? 12 gauge wires/15amp circuit breaker. In California.

Comment: They will work just fine.  I remember a story about an apprentice who broke all the tabs off all the receptacles he was "preparing" for use.  When the journeyman saw that, he made the apprentice pigtail and side-wire every single one of them.  Not sure if that ever happened of if it was just a made-up anecdote to scare the FNG into following directions.  Point is - they will work just fine.  The tab is for convenience only.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, pigtails will work. Since it is a 15A breaker you can use 12 AWG or 14 AWG. To avoid future confusion, using 12 AWG wire here is advisable because if the rest of the circuit is using 12 AWG wire then it could be upgraded to a 20A breaker.

Comment: Perfect answer for the question.   Just to be picky, with the low cost of outlets, the addition of extra connections(possible problem area) is almost a wash

Comment: But, with the added _time_ to go to the store to buy another one, it may work out in favor of using the outlet on hand. ;)

Comment: On a subtle and in this case admittedly unimportant point: the 15A receptacle has a yoke and feed through UL rated for 20A and I think should therefore technically be AWG12

Comment: @P2000 I disagree. If that were the case then 15A duplex receptacles would *always* require 12 AWG wire. That is definitely not the case. The feed-through design to handle 20A *allows* for use with a 20A circuit, as a 20A circuit may have 15A and/or 20A receptacles, as long as it has at least 1 20A receptacles or at least 2 15A receptacles (in this case duplex counting as 2, because the issue is to be able to make proper use of the full 20A, not to "count attached devices" as is the case with some other rules).

Comment: It would save almost nothing (Maybe $0.02?) to have "15A-only duplex" and "15A but 20A OK" receptacles but that would be a nightmare for electricians in the field.

Comment: It should be 12 ga wire, since the OP says the circuit is currently 12 ga., even though the breaker is 15 A.  If any 14 ga. wire is connected to the circuit, there should be a notation in the breaker panel so no-one sees the 12 ga wire at the breaker and decides it's safe to replace it with a 20 A breaker.

Comment: @Mark That is a separate issue about general practices. But I'll add a note.